# WPF simulated key down event not working as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard, virtual

I am creating a virtual number pad for touch input of numbers. I use the following function for raising the PreviewKeyDown and KeyDown events for the textbox:

```
    private void PerformKeyInput(Key key)
    {
        var target = this.dialogWindow.TextInputField; // Target element

        var previewKeyDownEvent = Keyboard.PreviewKeyDownEvent;
        target.RaiseEvent(
            new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, PresentationSource.FromVisual(target), 0, key)
            {
                RoutedEvent = previewKeyDownEvent
            });

        var keyDownEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent;
        target.RaiseEvent(
            new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, PresentationSource.FromVisual(target), 0, key)
            {
                RoutedEvent = keyDownEvent
            });
    }
```

and I also changed the UpdateSourceTrigger of the Text property binding to ProperyChanged.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TextBoxInput, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

My problem is right now that this function only works for Key.Back, Key.Left and Key.Right, but not for numbers like Key.Num0 or Key.D1 and so on. Why does that not work for sending number key strokes to the textbox ?

Comment: Have you tried to use [InputManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.inputmanager) features instead?

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I need here.